# Why is Vector Iterator not dereferencable?

Tags: c++

Getting vector iterator not deferencable for code below, but I don't see why.  I am simply iterating through the 2d array and instantiating all values to 0. Where am I iterating to an invalid location?

```
vector<vector<bool>> isduplicate(100);

        for(int i=0;i<isduplicate.size();i++){
            for(int s=0;s<isduplicate.size();s++)
            isduplicate[i][s]=false;
        }
```

Comment: Uhh...where's the iterator?

Comment: The code compiles for me, but crashes. Try putting the following line in the outer `for` statement, before the inner `for` statement: `isduplicate [i].resize (100);` That causes it not to crash since it will be a 100x100 array (which you assume in the inner `for` statement) and not a somethingx100 array. If you want a different size for your second dimension, specify that in the `resize` call and change the inner `for` statement to `s<isduplicate [i].size();`.

Comment: @chris: it should be `resize`, not `reserve`. `reserve` allows you to `push_back` until the requested size without new memory allocations, but to access the elements directly via the `[]` operator you must call `resize`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are iterating over `isduplicate` twice. You should iterate over `isduplicate[i]` in the inner loop:

```
vector<vector<bool>> isduplicate(100);
for(int i=0;i<isduplicate.size();i++){
    for(int s=0;s<isduplicate[i].size();s++)
       isduplicate[i][s]=false;
}
```

However, `isduplicate[i]` is empty for all `i`, therefore you won't iterate over anything in the inner loop.

If what you want is to have 100 vectors of 100 `bool`s containing the `false` value, then:

```
vector<vector<bool>> isduplicate(100, vector<bool>(100, false));
```

Should do it.